# What is API results on pub.dev?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I was searching some packages on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) and I noticed that some of the listed packages have API Results and some of them not.

I Wanted to know that what exactly it is and why only few packages contains API Results ?

Comment: are you using any filter?

Comment: i am not using any search filter.

Answer (score 0):

What I notice is that all packages having `API results` link, have written native code. So they invoke methods contains in a specific platform channel. Maybe it's just a link to have a look of what Apis they are using to actually communicate with the native platform